# Compile swift module/framework/library without xcode

Tags: xcode, swift

Writing a Swift framework, I'm wondering, can I compile this without using Xcode.
I tried 'swift' with the -module options, but the 'swift' command does not seem to produce any output no matter what I do.
'swiftc' with the -parse-as-library gives an 'Undefined symbol _main' error

So, how can I compile a swift library without Xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Swift 2.2 you can use `swiftc` to compiles a `swiftmodule` directly from the command line using the `-emit-module` flag like this:

```
$ swiftc -emit-module MyClass.swift
$ ls
MyClass.swift
MyClass.swiftdoc
MyClass.swiftmodule
```

Use the `--help` flag to see the full list of options. Also see [Creation of pure Swift module](http://railsware.com/blog/2014/06/26/creation-of-pure-swift-module/) blog post for a more complete tutorial.

---

```
Apple Swift version 2.2 (swiftlang-703.0.18.1 clang-703.0.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9
```